# How to make an event reoccur after a specific time in Flutter?

Tags: android, iphone, flutter

Imagine I would be trying to implement a button in my Flutter App. After the button is pressed once, it is supposed to be "deactivated" for 8 hours. After 8 hours, the button should be able to be clicked on again. How can I implement this?
How can I make my Flutter App recognize the time? Do I set a counter? Does the counter continue to "work", even if the app is closed? Do I need a database?

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to find something on Google, but I did find any clear explanation... ☹️

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish something like this by getting the [current date time](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) on a button press and persisting it in a [simple key/value store](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value) so that you can read it through an app restart